# How to get index number from within tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: using `indexPath` argument?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsindexpath

I want to change the `backgroundColor` of the `UITableViewCell` and thus want to get the index number of each table view cell, because I also want to change the color of those cells with respect to its index number.

However how can I get the index number from within `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? For example, in the following code (within `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

```
let numberOfCell = indexPath.length // always returns 2, even if I add more cells
println(indexPath) // returns <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
for i in 0..<numberOfCell {
    let alpha = CGFloat(1.0 - Double(i) / 10.0)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 227/256, green: 245/256, blue: 61/256, alpha: alpha)
}

return cell
```

I want to change the `alpha` value of each cell with respect to the index number, but the code above makes all the cell's `alpha` to `1.0`, because the `numberOfCell` is always `2`, even though my table view has four objects. I'm not sure why it always returns `2`. I added more cells but the result didn't change.

So why does it return `2` and how can I get the correct value of each index? What I want to get is `0` for the first cell, `1` for the second, `2` for the third, and goes on.

I also tried to access the `path` property of the index path as shown on the output of `println(indexPath)` above, but for some reasons `NSIndexPath` doesn't have such properties...

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it is so simple! Sorry I've just got to know that it is not from `NSIndexPath` but something that Apple calls " NSIndexPath UIKit Additions". (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `indexPath.row` or, if you are using sections too, try `indexPath.section` in addition. :)